# Using a MaskedEditExtender for a SSN but not saving the mask. ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display a social security number in a textbox when it's in read-only mode with dashes (easier to read and jot down if need be), like you would get using a MaskedEditExtender.

But the problem using MaskedEditExtender is you would then save the hyphens (the mask) with the number. We haven't ever saved our SSN's that way in SQL so I don't want to start that.

How do I go about this? Should I just format it when the page loads in the code behind (C#) and when they hit edit, remove the formatting there?

Comment: I should clarify, when I used the MaskedEditExtender in this example, it saved the hyphens. Maybe this is unusual behavior as I applied a mask for a phone number field and it does not save the extra formatting there. Hmm..

Answer (score 0):

Actually may have solved my own problem unless there's a better way of handling this. So in my "ShowPersonInfo" method, while I'm assigning text-boxes to the correct reader #, I tried this. When the user first sees page, the TxtSSN.textbox is in read-only status (and should see formatted SSN). When user hits edit, I change the control state of each textbox in a function and then call my ShowPersonInfo method again (should now edit without format).

```
            if (TxtSSN.ReadOnly == true)
            {
                string ssn1 = reader[4].ToString().Substring(0, 3);
                string ssn2 = reader[4].ToString().Substring(3, 2);
                string ssn3 = reader[4].ToString().Substring(5, 4);
                TxtSSN.Text = ssn1 + '-' + ssn2 + '-' + ssn3;
            }
            else
            {
                TxtSSN.Text = reader[4].ToString();    //unformatted
            }
```

Any other ways of going about this? I also have a miscclass.formatSSN that I could use instead of those substrings..